# Is there any way to fake the signature selector in Solidity for abi.encodeWithSelector?

Tags: solidity, abi, encodefunctioncall

Is there any way to fake the selector pointer for an arbitrary contract address call with `abi.encodeWithSelector`?

For example, I want to call a particular contract's `deposit(...)` method, but the contract calls `sender.putFunds.selector` like:

```
    (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(sender).call(
      abi.encodeWithSelector(ICaller(sender).putFunds.selector, callData)
    );
```

Is there any way I can force it to call `deposit(...)` instead of `putFunds(...)`, considering I have full control of the sender param which is retrieved as an input?

E.g., somehow faking the ABI so that it picks the function that I want.